# How to get an already created JSONStore in Mobilefirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I am trying to create a JSONStore in a Mobilefirst 7.0 hybrid app. The issue I am having is to be able to detect that the JSONStore is already there on subsequent runs of the app. The documentation says you have to have called WL.JSONStore.init(...) before calling WL.JSONStore.get(...).

So the question is, on subsequent runs of the app (meaning the app ran for the first time and created the JSONStore successfully) and this is a new run, what is the proper way to check if the JSONStore already exists?

If I have to call init again, how do I do that without wiping out what is there?

I am currently using this snippet of code to detect...

```
function checkJSONStore() {

alert("In checkJSONStore");

var collectionName;

try {
    // Check to see if JSONStore exists...
    collectionName = WL.JSONStore.get('appStore');

} catch (e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    alert("checkJSONStore: Exception = " + e.message);
}

alert("Returning from checkJSONStore: " + collectionName);

return collectionName;
}
```

Here is the code that create the store...it runs successfully.

```
function initJSONStore() {

console.log("In initJSONStore:");

var collectionName = "appStore";

var Data = {
 item: 'newinstall',
 value: 1
};

var JSONStoreCollections = {};
JSONStoreCollections[collectionName] = {};
JSONStoreCollections[collectionName].searchFields = {item: 'string'};

try {

    console.log("Destroy any collections before we start");

    WL.JSONStore.destroy().then(function () {
        //handle success
        console.log("initJSONStore: JSONStore destroy success");
    })
    .fail(function (error) {
        //handle failure
        console.log("initJSONStore: JSONStore destroy failure: " + error);
    });

    console.log("Calling WL.JSONStore.init");

    WL.JSONStore.init(JSONStoreCollections).then(function () {

        console.log("initJSONStore: JSONStore init success");

        WL.JSONStore.get('appStore').add(Data).then(function () {

            console.log("initJSONStore: JSONStore add success");

        }).fail(function (error) {

            console.log("initJSONStore: JSONStore add failure: " + error);
        });

    }).fail(function (error) {

        console.log("initJSONStore: JSONStore init failure");
    });
} catch (e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    //console.log("initJSONStore: Exception = " + e.message);
    alert("initJSONStore: Exception = " + e.message);
}
console.log("Exiting initJSONStore:");
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Calling `.init` again will not wipe your already-created collection. Only by calling `.destroy` will the already-created collection be destroyed... and so on the next init it will be (re-)created.

Comment: So what is the syntax to check it using init and get?

Comment: It's more of a custom implementation to check that. You can see an example in the following file. See the `onlineAuthenticationSuccess()` function: https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/OfflineAuthentication/blob/release71/apps/OfflineAuthSample/common/js/main.js

Comment: Idan, You mentioned "and so on the next init it will be (re-)created."...isn't the point of a persistent collection that the object was persisted and I can just fetch it? If I have to recreate it every time...then it is not really persisted...maybe that was a wrong assumption on my part?

Comment: It's not being recreated. If it exists, it is being used. It it is .destroyed() it will be recreated (empty).